# Back Button and Refresh Button in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I went through lot of tutorials and blogs but I could not able to implement what i need in the code. Can somebody help me on this?

I am trying to create a website. The basic structure(fields.html) is, it contains two text fields X and Y and one submit button. (All these three are put inside a Form).
Basically, when you enter some values in the two text boxes and press submit button, (It will connect to the query.php(action=”query.php”), where I have written the code to get the values(x and y) from the fileds.html and based on the received values(x and y),query.php would fetch some values from database and display those results by using the echo command ) a list of values will get displayed in the same page. I have used JQuery for this.

So here comes my requirement and issue I am facing:

**Requirements:**

**(SIMPLY I NEED THE FUNCTIONALITY IN THE PAGE:       http://nix.lv/history/demo.html  (Right Click on this page and you can view page source )   BUT IN THIS PAGE IT IS LOADING THE  STATIC PAGES(VIA ANCHOR TAB) BUT I WANT TO LOAD THE QUERY.PHP (VIA SINGLE SUBMIT BUTTON) WHICH IS DYNAMICALLY RUNNING BASED ON THE VALUES FROM FIELDS.HTML**

A. whenever I enter the values in the text boxes(x and y), the values should get displayed in the same page - (working -JQuery has been used).
B. whenever I press the refresh button, the already displayed results should NOT get vanished. Simply the page should get refreshed and it should display the result.- (Not working/ I am not sure how to implement it).
C. For example: For the first time, i have got a resultset1 by entering the values in the x and y text boxes in the fields.html. On the second time, I am entering
different values in the X and Y text boxes and obtaining resultset2 on the same fileds.html(resultset2 replaces the resultset1). Now, if it press back button, I should get the reslutset1. 
Simply to say, results has to be displayed in the same page but both refresh button and back/forward buttons have to work as expected by the end users.

**Issues:**

1. Refresh button is not working properly. When i press refresh button, the already displayed results are getting vanished along with the values entered in the Text boxes.(I don’t want this to happens mentioned in the point A)
2. Also, after getting the result set, if i enter a new values in the X and Y text boxes and if I press Submit button, Nothing is happening. -(Not working)
3. Also, I need back button to work properly as expected. - (Don’t know how to implement this)

*CODE:*

fileds.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>history plugin demo</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.history.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            var $ = {};
            // PageLoad function
            // This function is called when:
            // 1. after calling $.historyInit();
            // 2. after calling $.historyLoad();
            // 3. after pushing "Go Back" button of a browser
            function pageload(hash) {
                // hash doesn't contain the first # character.
                if(hash) {
                    // restore ajax loaded state
                    $j("#load").load(hash + ".php" , {X: $j("#ix").val(), Y: $j("#iy").val()});
                } else {
                    // start page
                    $j("#load").empty();
                }
            }

            $j(document).ready(function(){
                // Initialize history plugin.
                // The callback is called at once by present location.hash. 
                $j.history.init(pageload);

                // set onlick event for buttons
                $j("form[@rel='history']").submit(function(){
                    // 
                    var hash = this.action;
                    hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
                    // moves to a new page. 
                    // pageload is called at once. 
                    $j.history.load(hash);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Ajax load<BR>
            <form id="myForm" action='#query' method='POST' rel="history">
                X <BR>
                <input type="text" name="X" id="ix"><BR> <BR>
                Y <BR>                            
                <input type="text" name="Y" id="iy" > <BR> <BR>
                <input id= "sub" type="submit" value="Search" align="centre"/>
            </form>
        <hr>
            Loaded html:<BR>
            <div id="load"></div>
        <hr>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe you over-thought and over-engineered this problem. To get the history to stick, you need to use a standard form and the `GET` method, so that the form params are reflected in the query section of the URL. Also - get rid of all the jQuery - just submit the form to itself! `action="fields.html"`. You don't mention if you're being tasked to use AJAX - are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fields.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>history plugin demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $x = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['X'] ) ? $_REQUEST['X'] : null );
        $y = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['Y'] ) ? $_REQUEST['Y'] : null );
        $a = "{ $x , $y }";
    ?>
        Ajax load<BR>
            <form id="myForm" action='fields.php' method='GET' rel="history">
                X <BR>
                <input type="text" name="X" id="ix" value="<?=$x;?>"><BR> <BR>
                Y <BR>
                <input type="text" name="Y" id="iy" value="<?=$y;?>"> <BR> <BR>
                <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Search" align="centre"/>
            </form>
        <hr>
            Loaded html:<BR>
            <div id="load"><?=$a;?></div>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DevlshOne for your simple and powerful code!! So here comes, my next question (how can I apply this for the DYNAMIC links/anchor tags? ). PLEASE SEE BELOW :(I couldn't able to post my new code again, so please see below ).

Comment: Yes i have loaded <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
i will tell the things clearly .. we will take your code .. In that we will make a change , if i enter 1 in X text box and 2 in Y text box.. the result in the DIV(id="load") should be 1 and 2 as links. if you click on the link 1, some query has to run in background and it should finally display some data/details in DIV(id="result").. similarly, this should happen for the link 2.. How to achieve this? 
The main thing i need here is, the back/forward and refresh buttons has to work as expected

Comment: Hi DevlshOne, i have mentioned the exact need in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838588/clicking-on-a-link-should-display-the-result-in-same-page-back-and-refresh-butt   . Can you please help me on this?