# clicking on a link should display the result in same page .BACK and REFRESH button have to work normally

Tags: php, jquery

Basically in my webpage (fields.php), i have two text boxes(X and Y), one submit button and 2 DIV tags (DIV id="load" , DIV id="result"). Based upon the values we provide in the 
text boxes, a query will fetch some values from the database and display it inside the DIV id="load". Also, I have made the results to display as links(I have simply
made the results to display in between anchor tags). So here comes my question, once we click any of the links in the DIV id="load", a query should run in the back ground 
and it should display some kind values(fetched from database) inside the DIV id="result". **The most important thing i want is, the refresh/back/forward buttons should work normally.** 
By this i mean, For example, consider we have 4 links like wwww, xxxx, yyyy, zzzz inside DIV id="load" . so if i click on the link wwww, some result (processed by a query) should get 
displayed inside the DIV id="result". so now, if i click on xxxx, the result should replace the result for wwww. Also, if i press back button, i should see the result 
for wwww inside the DIV  id="result".

can some body help me on this? can any one provide the sample code.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>history plugin demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $x = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['X'] ) ? $_REQUEST['X'] : null );
        $y = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['Y'] ) ? $_REQUEST['Y'] : null );

    ?>
        Ajax load<BR>
            <form id="myForm" action='fields.php' method='GET' rel="history">
                X <BR>
                <input type="text" name="X" id="ix" value="<?=$x;?>"><BR> <BR>
                Y <BR>
                <input type="text" name="Y" id="iy" value="<?=$y;?>"> <BR> <BR>
                <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Search" align="centre"/>
            </form>
        <hr>
            <!-- here i am performing lot of database queries using php, but to show it to you, i have simplified the code!--> 
            <div id="load"><a href= "#")> <?php echo $x; ?> </a></div> <!-- so here whne i click on the link, i should pass the link as a text parameter to a  query  and display the result in div id= result IMPORTANT is : BACK AND REFRESH BUTTON SHOULD WORK AS NORMALLY !-->
            <div id="result"> </div>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to keep the back button to work normally, you can use get parameters to display the results even on clicking back button. I suggest you to change the following lines

```
<div id="load"><a href= "#")> <?php echo $x; ?> </a></div>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

to

```
<div id="load"><a href= "?link=<?php echo $x; ?>")> <?php echo $x; ?> </a></div>
<div id="result">
  <?php if (isset($_GET['link'])) {?>
  <!--do all the db related stuff here to fetch the link result-->
    <?php $link_clicked=$_GET['link'];?>
    <!--//this is my stuff-->
    <?php
      if ($link_clicked == 'link1') 
    echo "link1 results";
      else if ($link_clicked == 'link2')    
    echo "link2 results";
      else
    echo "no results";
    ?>
  <?php }?>
</div>
```

In the result div, the link which was clicked is obtained from the `$_GET` and the results for the particular link can be fetched from the database.
if you want to clear result div on clicking page refresh button, you can rewrite the browser query string using javascript. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Ayyapan, Hope you are from Tamil Nadu. I am also from TN only :)I Hope,i have understood your code.
Thanks for your suggestion. But i need the line <div id="load"><a href= "#")> <?php echo $x; ?> </a></div> 
TO LOAD THE DATA AS LINKS INSIDE THE DIV id="load" ..so i used                                                                            
<div id="load"><a href= "#" id='link')> <?php echo $x; ?> </a></div> 
 <div id="result"> 
 <?php if (isset($_GET['link'])) {
 
    $link_clicked = $_GET['link'];
   
    echo $link_clicked;  
    
    }
 
 else
 {
 echo ("aaaaa");
 }
 ?>
 </div>

Comment: But it is not working .. I am not able to echo the link .. i mean, i am not able to display the link inside DIV id="result".

Comment: can you help me on this ?

Comment: @user2609884: Sure!!! see my updated answer. You have to change your div which has id="load" also... Your anchor tag must have the link, not the #...

Comment: No. I cant have the link instead of #. My result which are displayed as links are dynamic . i guess u misunderstood my requirement. my links are dynamic because i am fetching the values from the database depending upon the values i am entering in the text boxes x and y. I have mentioned it in detail above .. please see that and please let me know if you can help me..

Comment: i can understand u :) by changing the href of anchor tags, u can get the name of the link which was get clicked. thats y i changed the href to have the link. when those links are clicked the control will be directed again to the same page, in which you can get the link argument inside "result div". you can reach me out @9944600218 for any queries

Comment: I have used the above code. As soon as i click on any link in the DIV id="load", i am able to see the some result(in this case i have just made to display the link itself) inside the DIV id="result". so it is working. But the links already inside the div id="load" is getting disappeared. I want those also to be present so that user can click on another link if the user want. How to achieve this?  i will call you after 6pm ..

Comment: the you need to work with AJAX yar. try to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

Comment: I used $.ajax and also tried $.get .. Most of the things are working properly.. But when i press refresh button, the content in the DIV id="result" is getting wiped out(even i can manage with this) and also the back button(i am more concerned about this) is not working properly for the DIV id ="result"..  main thing i notice is, whenever i press any link in the DIV id="load", a # symbol is appearing at the end of the URL.. can you help on this?

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I did the stuffs that u told over phone .. it works properly ... Thanks again !! if i need any help in future, can i call you ?